# SQL query the store that have more than one title on the order for pubs database

Tags: sql, database, pubs

In the `pubs` database I want to find out stores that have orders with more than one title on the order. I have joined the table but the logic to apply to find the order which have more than one title I can't understand

```
SELECT 
    title, stores.stor_name, S.ord_num, S.qty
FROM 
    sales S
JOIN
    titles T ON (S.title_id = T.title_id)
JOIN
    stores ON (S.stor_id = stores.stor_id)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n12rw.png)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
    SELECT 
    title, stores.stor_name, S.ord_num, S.qty
FROM 
    sales S
JOIN
    titles T ON (S.title_id = T.title_id)
JOIN
    stores ON (S.stor_id = stores.stor_id)
where S.ord_num in (

    SELECT 
    S1.ord_num
FROM 
    sales S1
JOIN
    titles T1 ON (S1.title_id = T1.title_id)
JOIN
    stores  st ON (S1.stor_id = st.stor_id)
    group by S1.ord_num
    having count( distinct title)>1
    )
```